# Worldpay Direct XML PHP Integration

Tags: php, xml, worldpay

I am writing a PHP script to take credit card & customer details on my site, send these details invisibly to Worldpay's server for processing and then take action based on the response (paid, failed etc).

My problem is that I can't seem to authenticate with Worldpay when sending my XML - I've replaced `MYMERCHANTCODE` with the proper merchant code.  This is the code I am using - it is based on [Worldpay's example](http://www.worldpay.com/support/kb/gg/submittingtransactionsdirect/dxml.html):

```
require_once 'HTTP/Request.php';

$xml='<?xml version="1.0"? encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE paymentService PUBLIC "-//WorldPay//DTD WorldPay PaymentService v1//EN""http://dtd.worldpay.com/paymentService_v1.dtd">
<paymentService version="1.4" merchantCode="MYMERCHANTCODE">
    <submit>
        <order orderCode="T0211010">

              <description>20 Tulip Bulbs from MYMERCHANT Webshops</description>

              <amount value="2600" currencyCode="EUR" exponent="2"/>

              <paymentDetails>
                  <VISA-SSL>
                      <cardNumber>4444333322221111</cardNumber>
                      <expiryDate>
                          <date month="09" year="2009"/>
                      </expiryDate>
                      <cardHolderName>J. Shopper</cardHolderName>
                      <cvc>123</cvc>
                      <cardAddress>
                          <address>
                               <street>47A Queensbridge Rd</street>
                               <postalCode>CB94BQ</postalCode>
                               <countryCode>GB</countryCode>
                          </address>
                      </cardAddress>
                   </VISA-SSL>
                   <session shopperIPAddress="123.123.123.123" id="0215ui8ib1" />
              </paymentDetails>

              <shopper>
                  <shopperEmailAddress>jshopper@myprovider.int</shopperEmailAddress>
                  <browser> [This example uses firefox 3.5.5 to demonstrate]
                       <acceptHeader>text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8</acceptHeader>
                       <userAgentHeader>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)</userAgentHeader>
                   </browser>
               </shopper>

        </order>
   </submit>
</paymentService>';

$dest='https://secure-test.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/jsp/merchant/xml/paymentService.jsp'; //for sandbox
//$dest='https://secure.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/jsp/merchant/xml/paymentService.jsp' //for production

$req =& new HTTP_Request($dest);
$req->setMethod(HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_POST);
$req->addHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
$req->addRawPostData($xml);
$req->sendRequest();
$req->getResponseBody();
echo nl2br(htmlentities($req->getResponseBody()));
```

When I run this, this is what is output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Authorization Required</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Authorization Required</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested. Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
</body></html>
```

Can someone please help with this?  The documentation says to add your IP address for requests to your Worldpay account, which I think I have done correctly.

Many thanks

**UPDATE:**

I've just realised that if I add my merchant ID & xml password before the URL, eg:

`$dest='https://MERCHANTID:PASSWORD@secure-test.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/jsp/merchant/xml/paymentService.jsp';`

It then authenticates, so I will answer my own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realised that if I add my merchant ID & xml password before the URL, eg:

```
$dest='https://MERCHANTID:PASSWORD@secure-test.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/jsp/merchant/xml/paymentService.jsp';
```

It then authenticates.  Hopefully this will save someone time as I couldn't find this in the documentation.

Comment: Hi, I am also trying to implement worldpay on a PHP site using XML direct method but whenever I try to connect I get error saying you are not authorized to view the file.. Can you tell me were you testing the payment gateway on localhost.

Comment: No, I was testing it on a live server on a proper domain. Let me know if I can help further.

Comment: @SammyBlackBaron Is the Merchant ID in uppercase yeah?

Answer (score 2):

C# worldpay xml api request to get the url for redirection *****************

I wasted heaps of time for integrating worldpay using xml for below urls and Finallly GOT IT.!!!!!!!!!!!!

the test URL to send XML messages to is: https://secure-test.worldpay.com/jsp/merchant/xml/paymentService.jsp

The live URL to send XML messages to is: https://secure.worldpay.com/jsp/merchant/xml/paymentService.jsp

all u need to do for authenticating is Get the 
New username or MerchantCode or Xml username 
and XML password

var uri = "https://secure.worldpay.com/jsp/merchant/xml/paymentService.jsp";

```
            var orderCode = (DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssff"));

            var sw = new StringWriterWithEncoding(_encoding);
            var xtw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
            xtw.WriteDocType("paymentService", "-//Worldpay//DTD Worldpay PaymentService v1//EN", "http://dtd.worldpay.com/paymentService_v1.dtd",null);
            xtw.WriteStartElement("paymentService");
            xtw.WriteAttributeString("version", "1.4");
            xtw.WriteAttributeString("merchantCode",MerchantCode);
            xtw.WriteStartElement("submit");
            xtw.WriteStartElement("order");
            xtw.WriteAttributeString("orderCode", orderCode);
            xtw.WriteAttributeString("installationId",installationId);
            xtw.WriteElementString("description",eventPaymentDetails.ECommerceGatewayReference + " - " + paymentDetails.ContactDetails.FirstName + " "+ paymentDetails.ContactDetails.LastName);
            xtw.WriteStartElement("amount");
            xtw.WriteAttributeString("currencyCode",CurrencyCode);
            xtw.WriteAttributeString("exponent","2");
            xtw.WriteAttributeString("value", amount);
            xtw.WriteEndElement(); //end amount
            xtw.WriteStartElement("paymentMethodMask");
            xtw.WriteStartElement("include");
            xtw.WriteAttributeString("code","ALL");
            xtw.WriteEndElement();  // end include
            xtw.WriteEndElement();  // end paymentMethodMask
            xtw.WriteStartElement("shopper");
            xtw.WriteElementString("shopperEmailAddress", paymentDetails.ContactDetails.EmailAddress);
            xtw.WriteEndElement();  // end shopper


            xtw.WriteStartElement("billingAddress");

            xtw.WriteStartElement("address");
            xtw.WriteElementString("address1", .AddressLineOne);
            xtw.WriteElementString("postalCode", AddressPostcode);
            xtw.WriteElementString("city", .AddressCity);
            xtw.WriteElementString("countryCode", paymentDetails.ContactDetails.AddressCountryTwoLetterCode);
            xtw.WriteEndElement();  // end address 

            xtw.WriteEndElement();  // end billingAddress

            xtw.WriteEndElement(); //end order
            xtw.WriteEndElement(); //end submit

            xtw.WriteEndElement(); //end payment service
            xtw.Close();

            // Send the Xml message to PXPost
            var wrq = WebRequest.Create(uri);
            wrq.Method = "POST";
            wrq.ContentType = "text/xml";
            var authString = _settings.XmlUserName + ":" + _settings.XmlPassword;
            var auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authString));
           wrq.Headers.Add("Authorization","Basic "+ auth);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var xmldata = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" + sw.ToString();
            byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmldata);
            wrq.ContentLength = b.Length;
            using (Stream s = wrq.GetRequestStream())
            {
                s.Write(b, 0, b.Length);

            }


            // Check the response
            using (var wrs = (HttpWebResponse) wrq.GetResponse())
            {

                if (wrs != null)
                {
                    var sr = new StreamReader(wrs.GetResponseStream());
                    var xd = new XmlDocument();
                    var responseText = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                    xd.LoadXml(responseText);
```

}
}

Hope this helps.
Thanks

Comment: basic auth in the header vs the url. interesting that it worked with the xmlusername and xmlpassword vs the merchant id like @SammyBlackBaron